# Spring Mvc Jquery Datatatables allways empty

Tags: jquery, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, datatables

I am using Spring Mvc and Jquery Datatables to display the data. The problem is that the table is **always empty** despite the controller action returning data. Below is the code:

**Controller code:**

```
@RestController
@Transactional
@RequestMapping("/api/employees")
public class EmployeesRestController {
    
@Autowired
private employeesRepository repository;
   
@RequestMapping(value = "listEmplyees", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<List<Employer>> employeesList() {
        List<Employer> list = employeesRepository.listEmplyees();
        try {
            return new ResponseEntity<List<Employer>>(list, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<List<Employer>>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
}
```

**Javascript code to load data into Datatables:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function() {
    
    var table = $('#employeesTable').DataTable({
        pageLength : 2,
        ajax : {
            url : '/employeesmanagement/api/employees/listEmplyees',
            type: 'GET',
            dataSrc: '',            
            success: function (response) {                
                  
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                  alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        },
        columns : [ {
                        title : 'id',
                        data : 'id'
                    }, {
                        title : 'name',
                        data : 'name'
                    } 
                 ]
    });
});

</script>
```

**Html code to create the table:**

```
<table id="employeesTable" style="width: 100%"></table>
```

Does anyone have an idea about the source of this error ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for those who have the same problem.Indeed the API returns an Array of JSON and not a simple Array, it is for this reason the display of the result returned by the API requires a different treatment.

Below is what the function of loading data looks like after modification.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.ajax({
        "url": "/employeesmanagement/api/employees/listEmplyees'",
        "type": "GET",
        "datatype": 'json',
        "success": function (data) {
            $('#employeesTable').DataTable({
                data: data,  
                columns: [
                    {
                        title : 'id',
                        data : 'id'
                    }, {
                        title : 'name',
                        data : 'name'
                    } 
                ]
            });
        }
    });
    
});
```

For more details see the following link: [How to load an array of JSON](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/32107/how-to-load-an-array-of-json-objects-to-datatables)